# UILabel not configuring to auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a table view app (see image.) The banner on the right of some cells is a boolean, which the user decides in the Add controller (prompted by the plus sign.) This banner is referred to as the urgent image in my code. The top label is called the subject label and the bottom label the deadline label.

[image]

The problem I have is with auto layout on the subject label. On some labels, the bottom is cut off, but on others it is not. It seems to be that when there is more than one line, the cut off takes place. The auto layout constraints look as follows.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here is my `viewDidLoad:`, where I added my self sizing cells code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agenda")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "subject", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            content = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Agenda]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: you've only included details of 1 constraint, we can't even see from the list what each constraint applies too, but the priorities and the compression and hugging details are also important, there just isn't enough information here...

Comment: Can you show all constraints of subject?

Comment: @Wain I know. I can't add all the constraints, but I added what I thought was the most important. Tell me what constraint you think the problem is with, and then I will inform you of it's details.

Comment: If possible Can you share your Xcode project?

Comment: @MoinShirazi I have added a better view of the subject constraints. Tell me which on you would like to see in more detail.

Comment: @NirmalChoudhari I'm afraid I cannot.

Comment: u have not added any bottom for subject label please add that it will solve the issue

Comment: @MoinShirazi This still doesn't fix the cut off.

Comment: subject label is having 2 top constraint remove one of it

Comment: @MoinShirazi Removing one does not fix the issue.

Comment: Make sure that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is NO for each label.

Comment: @Koen This didn't work.

Comment: OK, so are you setting compression and hugging constraints?

Comment: Yes, I already have. @Koen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cell is not big enough vertically to be able to not crop vertically your top Label.

**EDIT : the author is actually working on self-sized cells, so the first part of this answer is not a valid solution.**

What you can do is :

- Set your top label vertical compression resistance to 1000 (Required)
- Make your 20 vertical spacing constraint between your 2 labels a 750 priority (High priority) constraint

Edit :
Your cell being self-sized, it could come from a problem with your Label not updating well its layout if you change the Urgent Image View constraints/size. If that's the case you can try to change your Label custom class for this UILabel subclass :

**Objectice-C :**

```
@implementation AutoLayoutLabel

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
}

@end
```

In **Swift** it would be something like :

```
import UIKit    

class AutoLayoutLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)
    }

}
```

As you can't send your project, and we can't really see your constraints neither your code setup, I uploaded a working test project with the same cell design for you : [On the go multiline cell Xcode project](http://we.tl/rGV2dhDBic)

Reproduce what is done in this Xcode project to your project.

Comment: This still cuts off the label.

Comment: What is your table view row height ? Automatic dimension or a fixed one ?

Comment: It's automatic dimension. My cells are self-sized.

Comment: Ok, I had the same type of problem a while ago. Can you try this UILabel custom subclass : https://gist.github.com/false/2cef705b2339f6665b65
Just import it in your project, and in your storyboard, change the custom class for AutoLayoutLabel

Comment: I'm using Swift, so can you put the code snippet in your answer, and then I can implement it in my code.

Comment: There are a few errors in this code. One error is in the first line, saying **Use of undeclared type UILabel**.

Comment: You have to import UIKit in top of the file "import UIKit"

Comment: After I ran the code, the subject label is still being cut off.

Comment: Did you set an estimated row height ?

Comment: I set it in my main table view controller.

Comment: I see there is a constraint between Urgent Image View bottom and your Subject Label. We can't see it fully, what is this constraint ? Maybe you could share just your storyboard ?

Comment: This says that the bottom of the urgent label is equal to the bottom of the subject label.

Comment: I think you did not see my question : Could you share just your storyboard ?

Comment: Your Dead Line Label got an arrow in front of it. Are there constraints in that label ? You have got 2 top constraints and also 2 trailing constraints on your Subject Label. Even though there are not the problem here you should delete 1 of each. Without the storyboard I think we will need more screenshots to help you.

Comment: I deleted the constraints for the deadline label a few minutes ago, as they were unnecessary. I deleted one of the top constraints. There was only one trailing constraint for the Subject Label. And what screenshots do you want?

Comment: Ok I got it : the problem is your Urgent Image View height constraint. Remove it, or set its priority at 749.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. But, FYI, I have the yellow warning saying that my expected height of my subject label should be 18, but my actual is 26. When I press update constraints, nothing happens - the same warning appears.

Comment: Ok I have just saw you changed all your constraints. We can't read the full constraint names, it's a bit complicated. But it looks like you have got a constraint between the bottom of your view and your Urgent Image View ? What happens if you manually set a quite long text (that needs multi lines to display) to both labels ?

Comment: So what should I do, in terms of my constraints?

Comment: I updated my image in my questions, so you can see the constraints better.

Comment: See my edited post, I made a very small working project with the same cell design. Compare your constraints, compression resistance, hugging priority and  maybe your code.

Comment: I checked all of this, but it's still cut off :(

Comment: Did you try the Xcode project I have sent to you through wetransfert ? Can you see the self-sizing cells and multilines working ?

Comment: The self-sizing cells and multilines have always been working. The problem is that the subject label has a cut-off, and when I press update constraints on the auto layout warning, nothing happens (this warning is what I explained before in a previous comment.)

Comment: I meant : Do you see any glitch / cut off in the project I sent you ?

Comment: I can't build it, as there is no option for a simulator, and I can't use it on my phone because it is using iOS 9.3, where my phone isn't ready for it.

Comment: Change the deployment target version to your needs in the project general settings

Comment: I have, and so, no, the labels are not cut off, but I have conformed everything in your project.

Comment: What happens if you set a very long text to your subject Label in your project ?

Comment: The code produces as many lines as it needs to (up to 999), but the last line has a cut off bottom.

Comment: If you tell me how I can share my `Main.storyboard`, I could share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here are the steps to implement dynamic table Height based on multiple label lines. I have implemented this functionality in Table view in our swift app. Follow the steps and it will work:

1. Implement these two delegate function functions for table view:

   - estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath : return 50 (or the minimum height       you require for your table)
   - heightForRowAtIndexPath : return UITableViewAutomaticDimension ( this was introduced with iOS 8)
2. In your storyboard you will need to do this:

   - Set labels lines to 0.
   - Assuming you have two labels(label(top),Detail label(Below)): Don't assign bottom constraint to your label, assign leading, trailing and Top. Assign bottom constraint to your detail label with leading, trailing and Top and then set vertical spacing for detail label. Hopefully all autolayout errors should not exists by then.
3. Build and verify.

Let me know when it works !!!

Comment: This didn't fix the cut off on the subject label.

Comment: hmmm. Check Label Properties. Select Alignment to ----. Baseline : Align baseline, Line breaks: Truncate tail, Auto shrink: Fixed font size.

Comment: This was all previously implemented.

Comment: To what size then?

Comment: You can try reducing the text size in the label ... to pinpoint the issue...Also I would re create the label if that does not work. This issue has nothing to do with layout constraints or size...but is very rare...

Comment: I don't want to decrease the text size, and I tried recreating the label before, but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107315/discussion-between-the-incliner-and-swfapp).